# Minimum number validator is not working in Yii2 model

Tags: php, model, yii2

```
[['price'], 'integer', 'min' => 0, 'tooSmall' => 'Price cannot be less than 0'],
```

I have above rule in my model file. But while validating the model, return is `true` while passed `NULL` as price.

Any reason to this?

Comment: Adding this validation means your minimum value will be zero and if you try to enter a negative value then only this validation works.

Comment: `price` is Required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [`skipOnEmpty`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-validators-validator#$skipOnEmpty-detail) to `false` if you want to validate even when field empty, (by default it is set to `true`).

```
[['price'], 'integer', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'min' => 0, 'tooSmall' => 'Price cannot be less than 0'],
```